# Does a number matrix have its invariant factors??

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

I'm just confused by the following statement in my advanced algebra textbook:

> ***Frobenius Form***:
>   Let $A$ be an $n$th order square matrix over a number field $K$, whose invariant factors are:
>   $$1,\cdots ,1, d_1(\lambda),\cdots,d_k(\lambda)$$
>   Then we can obtain its Frobenius form as:
>   $$\cdots$$
>   **Proof**:
>   Note that $(\lambda I-A)$'s $n$th determinant factor is exactly $A$'s characteristic polynomial $|\lambda I-A|$. Because of the invariability of determinant factors under elementary transformations, we have
>   $$|\lambda I-A|=\prod_{i=1}^{k}d_i(\lambda)$$
>   $$\cdots$$

I don't understand why a **number** matrix should have something like invariant factors or determinant factors since all of its minors are pure numbers instead of polynomials? In fact, I strongly suspected that the author originally intended to mean "$(\lambda I-A)$'s invariant factors" rather than $A$'s invariant factors, which led me to believe that it was just a typo. But later in an exercise, it appeared again:

> The matrix 
>   $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
>   has the invariant factors: $1,\lambda,\lambda,\lambda^2$. 
>   $$\cdots$$

I got a shock. After calculation I found out that the invariant factors of $(\lambda I-A)$ "coincided" to be $1,\lambda,\lambda,\lambda^2$. This left me even more puzzled. Apparently that's not a typo, but why on earth did the author say "$A$'s" rather than "$(\lambda I-A)$"'s invariant factors? Or more probably, I'm just misunderstanding the use of this terminology? If so then can you point out where I'm wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the context is pointing you to a correct interpretation. Remember that for a matrix to have invariant factors its entries need to be viewed as elements of some PID. If the entries are in a field, then the invariant factors will inevitably be 1s and 0s only, and won't convey much information about the matrix (only its rank). I suspect that the author of your text has given a blanket statement to the effect that whenever they refer to invariant factors of a matrix $A$ with entries in a field, the really mean the invariant factors of $A-xI$.

Comment: After all, those invariant factors say much more about the nature of the linear transformation associated with $A$ (compare to Jordan canonical forms and such). I guess in this context it could also be interesting to study the invariant factors of a matrix with entries in a number field. Provided that those entries are algebraic integers, and that the field in question has class number one. The latter requirement is necessary for the existence of gcd's as elements of the ring of integers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen oh yes you r right!  I just found the statement in my book where I think I must have skipped....  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this stems from the fact that if you're given a finite dimensional vector space $E$ over any field $k$ and an endomorphism $f$, $E$ can be seen as a $k[x]$-module through  $x\cdot v=f(v)$.

This module is a finitely generated torsion module since $\chi_f(x)\cdot v=0$ (because of Cayley-Hamilton theorem). Hence by the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID, it has a sequence of invariant factors.

What is most important is that two matrices are similar if and only if they have the same invariant factors – which are also known as *similarity invariants*. To the difference of the computation of Jordan form, the computation of similarity invariants is entirely effective, as it doesn't require knowing the eigenvalues of the endomorphism.